# Grabbing value ranges with regex

Tags: regex, awk

I'm trying to write two awk commands to check a file to meet both conditions.

1. The first condition is that it will output any line that has 'deny=n' where n is either 0 or is greater than 10, and ignore commented out lines.

Example:

```
test deny=1
test2 deny=0
test deny=4
#test=3 deny=0
test deny=44
```

I want it to display:

```
test deny=44
test2 deny=0
```

Here is my current regex that doesn't appear to be outputting that correctly:

```
awk '$1 ~ /[^#]*/ && ! /deny=([1-9]|10)/' /etc/pam.d/system-auth
```

2. My second awk I'd like to only display the line where deny=n where n is anything between 1-10.

Here is my current line for this output

```
awk '$1 ~ /[^#]*/ &&  /deny=1[1-9]/ &&  /deny=[2-9][0-9]/' /etc/pam.d/system-auth
```

Any thoughts on how to improve these? I wanted to see how this works in shell/bash before trying to port it to ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk` command with custom field separator:

```
awk -F '[= \t]+' '!/^[ \t]*#/ && $2 == "deny" && ($3==0 || $3>10)' file

test2 deny=0
test deny=44
```

- `-F '[= \t]+'` sets input field separator as `=` or a space or a tab
- `!/^[ \t]*#/` will match anyline that is not commented

---

**EDIT:**

As per comments below if `deny` can appear anywhere in input then use:

```
grep -E '^([[:blank:]]*[^#].*)?deny=(0\b|1[1-9]|[2-9][0-9])' file

test2 deny=0
test deny=44
```

`(0\b|1[1-9]|[2-9][0-9])` will match either `0` or any 2 digit number greater than `10`.

Comment: Does this assume that deny is at a certain point on the line? I was looking to use regex to check for it at any position on the line

Comment: If `deny` can appear anywhere then I suggest using `grep` as in my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

It always surprises me when people say they need a numeric comparison and then look for a way to cludge it with regexps. If you want to compare numbers, use a numeric comparison:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^[^#]*deny=([0-9]+)/,a) && (a[1]==0 || a[1]>10)' file
test2 deny=0
test deny=44

$ awk 'match($0,/^[^#]*deny=([0-9]+)/,a) && (a[1]>=1 && a[1]<=10)' file
test deny=1
test deny=4
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), with other awks it'd be substr() or sub() and a variable, e.g.:

```
$ awk '{n=$0} sub(/^[^#]*deny=/,"",n) && (n+0==0 || n+0>10)' file
test2 deny=0
test deny=44

$ awk '{n=$0} sub(/^[^#]*deny=/,"",n) && (n+0>=1 && n+0<=10)' file
test deny=1
test deny=4
```

Note that you need to add zero in the non-gawk version since the first operation we do on `n` is a string one (`sub()`) so at that point awk "knows" that `n` contains a string (despite it "looking like" a number which is why the gawk version doesn't require this special treatment) and so to use it as a number afterwards we need to explicitly cast it to a number by doing a numeric operation (`+`) on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. the string `deny=44` DOES match the regex `/deny=([1-9]|10)/` -- you need a word anchor there: `/deny=([1-9]|10)\>/`
2. the string `#test=3` DOES match the regex `/[^#]*/` because there are zero or more non-"#" characters

You want

```
awk '$1 !~ /^#/ && ! /deny=([1-9]|10)\>/'
```

Looks like you can benefit from a regular expression tutorial online. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info